# Converting a program from console to windows form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, console

I am trying to convert a program from console to windows form but the problem is that the output is not showing on my textbox. My program is that user inputs how many number of rows.

[image: Example output in the picture]

```
    int n = int.Parse(textbox1.Text);
    int counter1 = 1,counter2 = 1,size = n + n -1;
       for(int i = 0;i<size;i++){
       for(int j = 0;j<size;j++){
    
    if(i<n-1){
    if(j<n-1){
    if(i == j){
        textBox2.Text =  "{0} " + counter1;
        counter1++;}
        else{
        textBox2.Text = " ";
    } }
    else{
            if(i + j == size-1){
            textBox2.Text =  "{0} " + counter2;
        counter2++;}                    
            else{
            textBox2.Text = " ";
        }
    } }
        else if(i == n- 1 && j == n-1){
        textBox2.Text =  "{0} " + counter1;
        counter1--;
        counter2--;   }
            else if(i == n-1 && j != n-1){
            textBox2.Text = " ";
            }
            else if(i > n-1){
            if(j>n-1){
                if(i == j){
                textBox2.Text = "{0} " + counter1;
                counter1--;
            }           
                else{
            textBox2.Text = " ";
        } }
        else
        {
            if(i + j == size-1){
            textBox2.Text = "{0} " + counter2;
            counter2--;
        }
            else{
            textBox2.Text = " ";
            }
        } } }
            textBox2.Text = " ";
            }
```

The program is to display the input x number pattern. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like your resetting the content of the text box every time you set a value.  Looks like you want to set textbox = texbox2.Text + "your new text"?

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting the text of textBox2 every time. You should use the += operator instead of =.
Side note: You should also use the special '\n' character when you need a new line.

Comment: Do u mean by using += instead of = is that I Change every "textBox2.Text += "{0}" ?? Because I tried it and it only showed bunch of numbers with the {0} and it still is not forming the X pattern. 

Example I enter 2, the result i get is {0} 1 {0} 1  {0} 2  {0} 1 {0} 1

Comment: @Spooderman If you want to substitute variables into {0}, {1}, ... you need to use the String.Format() method. More info about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-5.0#Starting